# MariaDB syntax error when using IF statements

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MariaDB using the code below.

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE P5();
BEGIN
IF 1=1 THEN
    SELECT 1;
END IF;
END//
```

When I run the code, I receive a syntax error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';

BEGIN
IF 1=1 THEN
    SELECT 1;
END IF;
END' at line 1
```

I realise that I could use an `IF ()` function in this case, but I need to be able to use `IF` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of adding semicolon after procedure name.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE P5()
BEGIN
IF 1=1 THEN
    SELECT 1;
END IF;
END//
```

Check [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/83o7jooHZvT4vhFr2REoYu/0)

Refer: [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)